# Find the correlation between $Z_1$ and $Z_2$

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

Let $X_1\sim N(3,9)$ ,$X_2\sim N(0,1)$, $X_3\sim N(1,1)$. They are independent

Also assume that,

$Z_1 = 2X_1+3X_2-4X_3$ and $Z_2 = 3X_1-2X_2+1X_3$

My approach:

$\mu(Z_1) = 2\times3+3\times 0-4\times 1$

$\mu(Z_2) = 3\times3-2\times 0+1\times 1$
\begin{align*}
var(Z_1) &= 2^2(E[X_1^2]-(E[X_1])^2)+3^2(E[X_2^2]-(E[X_2])^2)+4^2(E[X_3^2] -(E[X_3])^2)
\\ &=2^2(var(X_1)+(E[X_1])^2-(E[X_1])^2)+3^2(var(X_2)+(E[X_2])^2-(E[X_2])^2)+4^2(var(X_3)+(E[X_3])^2 -(E[X_3])^2)
\\  &= 2^2(var(X_1))+3^2(var(X_2))+4^2(var(X_3))
\\ &= 2^2\times9+3^2\times 1+4^2\times 1
\end{align*}
Did I correctly derive the the mean and variance?

Comment: is $X_1,X_2,X_3$ independent?

Comment: In variance calculation: usually ppl write the third line directly: Why did you tried to calculate third line from first line?(just a lot of extra meaningless work, you know)

Comment: Yes they are independent. Can you please tell me how to calculate the correlation from this point?

Answer (score 1):

Means seem OK.

The variance computation is needlessly messy, and (possibly) wrong. Without some work, you wouldn't know $E(X_1^2)$.

The applicable formula for independent RVs gives

$$Var(Z_1) = Var(2X_1+3X_2-4X_3) = 2^2Var(X_1) + 3^2Var(X_2) + 4^2Var(X_3).$$

Various notations are used for normal distributions. In *your* notation $N(3,9),$
is 9 the variance or the SD?

Comment: That is S.D. I am using the following formula to calculate the covariance matrix. Is it correct??  $var(Z_1+Z_2) = var(Z_1)+var(Z_2)+2*Cov(Z_1,Z_2)$

Comment: OK, but be careful finding the variance of he sum. Perhaps more direct:
covariance is linear in both arguments. Difficult to advise ,not knowing what's in your text.